# Actionscript 3 Using ColorPicker to change multiple objects along a timeline

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, actionscript

I am relatively new to actionscript 3 but here is what I have so far.

```
import fl.controls.ColorPicker;
import fl.events.ColorPickerEvent;
import flash.geom.ColorTransform;

var stripecolor:ColorTransform = new ColorTransform();

var StripeArray:Array=new Array();
StripeArray.push(stripe1,stripe2);
for (var j:int=0;j<StripeArray.length;j++)

StripePicker.addEventListener(ColorPickerEvent.CHANGE,colorChangerStripe);

function colorChangerStripe(event:ColorPickerEvent):void{

    stripecolor.color = StripePicker.selectedColor;
    for(var j:Object in StripeArray) {
    StripeArray[j].transform.colorTransform = stripecolor ;}

}
```

What I am trying to do is allow the use to pick an initial color that will propagate though the animation. Changing multiple movieclips on multiple frames throughout the flash.

The "stripe1" object is on the first frame, "stripe2" is further along in the timeline. Without stripe2 the code runs fine and changes are seen as expected. With stripe2 I get errors telling me it cannot find it as follows. 
"TypeError: Error #1009: Cannot access a property or method of a null object reference."
I think I understand why, at the time the code is run, there is no stripe2 present.

I can't seem to find any information that would demonstrate a fix to this problem, so I feel I am missing something basic.

Comment: Of course if `stripe2` is null you will get an error. Try to set the color just when your object is available.

Comment: That's so obvious it hurts!
I added the set color code to trigger once per frame. It feels messy but works. Thanks Akmozo!

Answer (score 0):

As Akomzo mentioned in the comments.
I will be initiating the color change script on any frame where there is a stripe that needs it.
Its messy and time consuming, but it works. 
It also means the array is useless unless there are multiple stripes on one frame.